# 9T SRAM Circuit Supporting 1-bit Multiplication

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, pmos, sram, nand

I was reading a paper that added a 3T NAND gate, consisting of two NMOS and one PMOS, to the regular 6T SRAM, achieving 1-bit multiplication. However, I'm struggling to understand how the NAND part of the circuit accomplishes this multiplication. This gate circuit is quite different from other implementations I've seen before.

I know this NAND introduces two lines to the Data and Data Bar reference points in the SRAM, which might help to fetch one multiplier from the SRAM. There's also an input line named 'W', which I think is the other multiplier. Without the source and drain of the transistors in the NAND gate being labeled, how should I analyze its function?

I tried to replicate the circuit depicted in the image using Virtuoso, but the simulation results indicate that it functions as an AND gate. Likewise, I am puzzled as to why 1-bit multiplication would necessitate a NAND gate rather than an AND gate. Could this be a small oversight by the author of the paper?
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Welcome! Could you link the paper and/or include (with attribution) the relevant schematics? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry about that, my upload failed the first time. I'm sure the schematic is ready now.  
Thank you for your help!
You can read the paper here
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/10185311

Comment: No problem! I'm actually more an analog guy than a digital guy, so I'm not sure of the answer myself, but I'm curious as well to learn about this circuit and the overall answer.

Comment: `Without the source and drain of the transistors in the NAND gate being labeled` actually, the transistors *are* symmetrical - what makes one end of the channel of a discreet (three terminal) MOSFET a source is the connection to bulk. In ICs, bulk (or "well") is typically shared among many transistors. (In power MOSFETs thermal properties complicate the picture.)

Comment: @BlueSun - Hi, Thanks for mentioning the [image source](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/10185311) in an earlier comment. However, to comply with the relevant [site rule](/help/referencing), the source link & name (i.e. citation) needs to be in the question (or answer) not just in comments. || Since "your" link is paywalled by IEEE, I searched and I *think* I found the same paper [here](http://nu-vlsi.eecs.northwestern.edu/CIM_CPU_VLSI2023.pdf). Please compare the paywalled paper at "your" link with that one at "my" link. If it's the same, please add both links into the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is an AND gate, not a NAND gate.

The two transistors between "W" and "OUT" are a transmission gate, which is enabled if the RAM cell contains a one, disabled otherwise. When the gate is disabled, "OUT" is pulled low by the third transistor. But if the RAM cell contains a one, then "OUT" is equal to "W", which is the same function as an AND gate.